# Java Regular expression to remove a pattern within opening and closing braces { }

Tags: java, regex

I need to remove anything starting from `(test)` within curly braces `{}`

Example

```
String abc = message for {user.username (50)} (test)
```

I need to remove `(50)` only within the `{ }` and nowhere else within the string  example `(test)` should not be removed from the string `abc`.

Thanks
Vijay

Comment: your question is unclear. Do you want to remove everything inside paretheses which in turn are inside braces?

Comment: Is nested parentheses of any concern?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)  What is  your question?  Note that SO is not a code generation machine.

Comment: You need a pushdown automaton, not a finite one.

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you need, with a look behind of 5000 characters (increase as needed).

```
String test = "some message (blah) { foo (bar) is (baz) } (test)"; 
String result = test.replaceAll("(?<=\\{[^\\}]{0,5000})\\(.*?\\)", "");
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Or `"\\(.*?\\)(?=[^{]*\\})"`; with the lookahead version you don't have to resort to that arbitrary-maximum-length hack.

Comment: @AlanMoore That doesn't work, at least as used in the above replaceAll.  Not sure of any way to replace the hack in the lookbehind (I had heard previously that you could do unbound lookbehinds that were simple bound from 0 to max int, but that does not seem to work) and I am not going to spend any more time on it.

Comment: the above code does not work for me example: " (start) {some message (test) } (123)" I need to delete (test) within curly braces and not anywhere in the string. Thanks

Comment: @user1096909 The code in the answer works, the code in the comment doesn't...  or are you having trouble with the code in the answer?  (I've tested it, it works for your scenario as written).

Comment: the code in the comments work for me and not the code in the answer. this particular statement works "\\(.*?\\)(?=[^{]*\\})" but the problem with this code is if the string starts with bracket example "(this) example {testing (50)}" it deletes everything starting from "(this)" until the end of the curly brace "}" Thanks Vijay